# Как открыть еще один терминал с помощью одной программы питон?

Tags: python

Т.е. запускаем один файл, а он открывает второй терминал и туда что-нибудь выводит

Comment: Это зависит от операционной системы. В Windows можно сделать, надо будет запустить отдельный процесс и передавать ему данные. В Linux универсального способа нет, но для конкретной графической оболочки есть методы для запуска нового окна терминала. Или `tmux`/`screen`.

Comment: Лучше выводите что-нибудь в файл. Пользователь сам откроет новый терминал и будет следить за текстом попадающим в файл.

Comment: Для Windows. Запустить отдельную консоль несложно - `subprocess.run("start python proc2.py", shell=True)` Вот только передать туда что-нибудь после запуска уже чуть сложнее.  Можно попробовать модуль `xmlrpc.server/client`, там все достаточно просто. Чисто для вывода удобнее сервер во втором процессе.

Comment: Спасибо, Алекс, очень помог, ну а с данными во втором терминале разберусь